# What's the BAB for Spiritual Weapons created by Crown of Swords?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

[Crown of Swords](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/crown-of-swords) creates something like [Spiritual Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spiritual-weapon), but the user has to spend charges to allow the weapon to continue attacking.

Now, Spiritual Weapon says that the weapon gets the BAB of the caster plus the caster's wisdom modifier as its attack bonus. But in the case of Crown of Swords, the item user isn't necessarily the caster.

Would the weapon get the BAB + WIS of the user or the BAB+ WIS (at the time of creation) of the person who made the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRD, Magic Items:

> Magic items produce spells or spell-like effects. For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + the ability modifier of the minimum ability score needed to cast that level of spell.

A spell being cast from a wondrous item works similarly, it assumes the lowest caster level and lowest ability score required to cast it. It doesn't speak to BAB but one could assume that it works the same way via parallelism.

A minimum L3 cleric making the crown of swords would have BAB +2, WIS 12 (+1) for a total of +3 on the attack roll.

Comment: And +1 on the damage roll.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it makes the most sense with the rules. However, after careful consideration, I've decided to let it use the BAB and WIS of the user in the game I'm running, because otherwise, the item becomes quite useless very fast. If it's always a +3, as soon as the party is facing things with 23 or more AC, you'd have to roll a 20 to hit with any of its attacks. And that starts happening at fairly low levels. Since it's a 6000gp item, it would only be useful for just a couple of levels when you first might be able to get it.

Comment: Yeah but that makes it super powerful for 6000gp at high level, is the real issue... You basically get an attack per round as an immediate action, that's a really darn good ability.

Comment: But only 10 attacks per day, and at least for my party, no one has more than a +2 WIS mod, so it'll mostly just be the BAB contributing to its attack. Also, the damage will always be 1d8 + 1. Which at higher levels is not so incredibly much. The way I see it, it's nearly equivalent to adding Flaming onto their weapon (which essentially costs an extra 6000gp to add onto a +1 magic weapon), but it does slightly more damage and can only be used 10 times per day.

Answer (score -1):

After reading the item description and the spell, due to the way that magic items normally function it would be the caster level of which the item has been made with. The item clearly states near the top that its caster level is 3. So the sword would do 1d8 +1. The attack however would be based on your stats since its unrealistic to have the stats of whatever magic user created it, this is also because the spell says "you". Which would normally be the caster but the person who activates the item should be valid.